# How to check in python if all files in a folder have different content?

Tags: python, windows, compare, directory

I have a huge folder with a lot of documents (`.txt`files). I would like to check if there are some identical content of some files. The filenames are all unique.

I know how to compare two files as follow:

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('file1.txt', 'file1.txt')
True
>>> filecmp.cmp('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
False
```

But I would like to compare all files at once. Does somebody know how I could do that?

Comment: 1) compute hash or checksum of all files. 2) use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count occurences. 3) keep entries with a count ≥ 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way to classify all your .txt files by MD5 sum:

```
import glob
import hashlib
import json
from collections import defaultdict


def md5(filename):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()


dct = defaultdict(list)

for filename in glob.iglob('**/*.txt', recursive=True):
    dct[md5(filename)].append(filename)
```

So if you just want to check which ones will have the same content you just query like:

```
print([v for k, v in dct.items() if len(v) > 1])
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need python for that, just run:

```
md5sum * | sort >filelist.txt
```

and then see if the consecutive files have the same MD5 sum.